# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A0C6F): Not enough space on temporary disk

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

When I am trying to create an access workspace in VB.net using the below code I get an error as

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A0C6F): Not enough
>   space on temporary disk.

```
privDBEngine = New DAO.PrivDBEngine ()

workspace = privDBEngine.CreateWorkspace("", AccessUser, AccessPassword, DAO.WorkspaceTypeEnum.dbUseJet)
```

Not sure whats causing this issue.

My C:\ drive memory is large enough.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using `DAO.PrivDBEngine`? Have you tried using `DAO.DBEngine` to see if it behaves in the same way?

Comment: Force the project to be x86 (32 bits) and see if that helps

Comment: Drive might be large; what matters is the free space. You could check the environment variables TMP and TEMP at both user and system level to see what drive(s) they point to (Control Panel, System) Then, check the drive free space for those drives before running the program and at the moment you get the error ( without dismissing the error message.)